# Matplotlib unexpected contains_point() result in nested donut chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having issues trying to get `Patch.contains_point()` method to work in nested donut chart. Here's my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('equal')
width = 0.3

pie, _ = ax.pie([120, 120], radius=1)
plt.setp(pie, width=width, edgecolor='white')

pie2, _ = ax.pie([60, 60, 37, 40, 29, 10], radius=1 - width)
plt.setp(pie2, width=width, edgecolor='white')

def button_release(event):
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        pos = [event.x, event.y]
        for i, p in enumerate([pie, pie2]):
            for j, w in enumerate(p):
                if w.contains_point(pos):
                    print(i, j)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_release_event", button_release)
plt.show()
```

The result is this chart:

[image]

The printed 'coordinates' are exactly as expected until the outer ring contains just one value and the chart looks like this:

[image]

In this case clicking on any wedge always results with positive result on outer ring. So when I click on outer ring I'm getting `(0, 0)`, that's fine. But when I click on inner ring's first wedge, I'm getting `(0, 0)` and `(1, 0)`. Same with other wedges on the inner ring.

Also I have noticed that in this case clicking on the empty circle inside the chart results in false positive `(0, 0)`, while it is not the case on the first chart.

Is this how `contains_point()` is suppose to work?